# Passing records: constref vs var

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I've been reading about the various means of passing parameters to procedures and functions, but I am still confused about the semantics of `var` and [`constref`](https://wiki.freepascal.org/Constref) as they apply to records (this is regarding the Free Pascal dialect of the language, v3.x).

My understanding is that:

1. Both `var` and `constref` enforce that a parameter is passed by reference
2. `var` suggests mutation of the argument is possible, while `const[ref]` does not

This distinction makes sense for simple types such as numbers and strings, but what about structured types? Assuming I have the following record:

```pascal
  A = record
    x: Integer;
  end;
```

And a procedure that acts on `A`s like the following:

```pascal
procedure proc(var rec: A);
begin
  rec.x := 42;
end;
```

i.e. `proc` does *not* reassign `rec`, but it *does* perform a side-effect in that it mutates fields of its formal parameter. I was able to compile this just fine under `fpc 3.0.4` with either `var` or `constref`, but my gut feeling is that `rec` should probably be declared as `var` here so as to indicate that the memory occupied by this record instance is changed by the procedure call?

In other words, should I use `constref` whenever I do not reassign a formal parameter and I want to enforce passing a record by reference, or only when that record is also truly immutable in the sense that the procedure does not write to any of its fields either? But also, what *is* the difference from the perspective of the compiler, since apparently it does not catch the fact that even with `constref` I am able to mutate fields of a record that is passed by reference?

**UPDATE:**

As the responder points out, the above sample code *should* (and does) fail to compile with `fpc` 3.x; I had oversimplified. In my case, the `A` record was holding references to dynamic arrays, and it was those array elements that I was able to reassign through a `constref` parameter, which confused me:

```pascal
A = record
  x: Array of Integer;
end;

procedure proc(constref rec: A);
begin
  rec.x[0] := 42; // this works
end;
```

It sounds like the reason is that a dynamic array is essentially just a pointer, and `arr[i]` is syntactic sugar to dereference that pointer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation to which you link explains that `constref` differs from `const` only in that `constref` arguments are always passed by reference, whereas `const` arguments can be passed by reference or value as determined by the compiler.

So, this code

```
procedure proc(constref rec: A);
begin
  rec.x := 42;
end;
```

should result in a compilation error. When I attempt to compile this in the versions of fpc available at https://godbolt.org/ (2.6.0, 2.6.2, 2.6.4, 3.0.2, 3.0.4 and 3.2.0) the compiler rejects it as invalid in all cases.

If this code compiles in your installation of fpc 3.0.4 then that is a compiler bug that should be reported. However, that seems at odds with what I have observed, so I suggest that you carefully re-check your findings.

Comment: Thank you! Your answer pointed me in the right direction. I fooled myself by simplifying the code sample incorrectly: in fact, in my own code, the `record` was holding a reference to a dynamic array, whose elements I am able to reassign through a `constref` record, but the array field itself I cannot (as expected.) This is still interesting, since it means that `constref` does not actually guarantee immutability of the argument passed, but I suppose it does not claim anywhere it would, I just assumed it would. I'll update the question to clarify.

Comment: That godbolt site is great. I played around with it more and found that static arrays are also protected by having their elements altered through a `constref` record containing that array, while dynamic arrays are not. I believe this is because the latter are stored on the heap and are not technically part of the record value itself? It is odd, however, that the compiler does not simply prevent reassignment at the syntactic level to anything reachable by `rec`, but I'm probably missing something.

Comment: This isn't really about `constref`. It's about `const`. All `constref` does is force a `const` arg to be passed by ref. I don't think it's about the heap or stack. Remember that records can be allocated on the heap. I think what is key here is that a dynamic array is essentially just a pointer, and `arr[i]` is syntactic sugar to derefence that pointer.